# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, visual-studio-2012, jasmine

OK,
So I am trying to get started unit testing with Jasmine on an Angular JS project for the first time, and I am hitting a few road blocks.

I am following the very good reference in this blog post about how to [set this all up in Visual Studio](http://www.rosher.co.uk/post/2013/10/22/Unit-Testing-AngularJS-with-Jasmine-Chutzpah-and-Visual-Studio.aspx)

My test is in a Class Library project and looks like so:-

```
/// <reference path="../../../../src/tasks.web/scripts/angular-1.2.10.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../src/tasks.web/scripts/angular-route-1.2.10.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../src/tasks.web/scripts/app.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../src/tasks.web/scripts/controllers.js" />
/// <reference path="../lib/angular/angular-mocks.js" />

describe("TaskListController", function () {
    beforeEach(module('taskApp.controllers'));

    it("has tasks defined", function() {
        var $scope = {};
        $controller("TaskListController", { $scope: $scope });
        expect($scope.tasks).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

The rest of my app looks like this:-

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("taskApp", [
    "ngRoute",
    "appControllers"
]);

app.config(["$routeProvider",
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when("/tasks", {
                templateUrl: "partials/task-list.html",
                controller: "TaskListController"
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/tasks"
            });
    }
]);
```

controller.js

```
var appControllers = angular.module("appControllers", []);

appControllers.controller("TaskListController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = {};
});
```

All the referenced files are there (no 404s). Visual Studio find the test fine and runs it, however I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $controller`

[image]

Any help gratefully received as I know I am really close to having this working, and I know it is just something simple that I am missing.

Comment: In the test the name of the controllers module has a different name. 'beforeEach(module('taskApp.controllers'));' should be instead 'beforeEach(module('appControllers'));' ?

Comment: thanks that didn't quite do it, but combining it with @Michael 's suggestion resolved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inject the `$controller`. One way would be:

```
it("has tasks defined", inject(function($controller) {
   var $scope = {};
   $controller("TaskListController", { $scope: $scope });
   expect($scope.tasks).toBeDefined();
}));
```

Also you need to reference the correct module in the `beforeEach`

So you need to do the following:-

```
beforeEach(module('appControllers'));
```